# What is the time complexity of the following dependent loops?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have a question that needs answer before an exam I'm supposed to have this week.

```
i = 1;
while (i <= n)
{
    for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
        printf("*");
    j *= 2;
    i *= 3;
}
```

I have those dependent loops, I calculated the outer loop's big O to be `O(logn)`.

The inner loop goes from `1` to `i - 1` for every iteration of the outer loop,
the problem I'm having with this is that I do not know how calculate the inner loop's time complexity, and then the overall complexity (I'm used to just multiplying both complexities but I'm not sure about this one)

Thanks a lot!

P.S: I know that the `j *= 2` doesn't affect the `for` loop.

Comment: Where did you get this from? The statement `j*=2` is completely pointless. It does not affect anything.

Comment: I thought it was obvious so I didn't say that, I'll add that in an edit though, thanks. My professor posted this question for my class

Comment: The inner loop is being run 0, then 2, then 8, etc. times (3*\*0-1, 3*\*1-1, 3*\*2-1, etc.).  The time is dominated by the final iteration of the outer loop, which is `O(n)`, which is also the overall time complexity.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought actually but I just had to double check.

Answer (score 0):

As you recognized, computing the complexity of a loop nest where the bounds of an inner loop vary for different iterations of the outer loop is not as easy a simple multiplication of two iteration counts.  You need to look more deeply to get the tightest possible bound.

The question can be taken to be asking about how many times the body of the inner loop is executed, as a function of *n*.  On the first outer-loop iteration, *i* is 1, so *j* is never less than *i*, so there are no inner-loop iterations.  Next, *i* is 3, so there are two inner-loop iterations, then eight the next time, then 26 ... in short, 3<sup>*i*-1</sup> - 1 inner-loop iterations.  You need to add those all up to compute the overall complexity.

Well, that sum is Σ<sub>*i* = 1, floor(log *n*)</sub> (3<sup>*i*-1</sup> - 1), so you could say that the complexity of the loop nest is

O(Σ<sub>*i* = 1, floor(log *n*)</sub> (3<sup>*i*-1</sup> - 1))

, but such an answer is unlikely to get you full marks.

We can simplify that by observing that our sum is bounded by a related one:

= O(Σ<sub>*i* = 1, floor(log *n*)</sub> (3<sup>*i*-1</sup>))

.  At this point (if not sooner) it would be useful to recognize the sum of powers pattern therein.  It is often useful to know that 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + ... 2<sup>k - 1</sup> = 2<sup>k</sup> - 1.  This is closely related to base-2 numeric representations, and a similar formula can be written for any other natural number base.  For example, for base 3, it is 2 * 3<sup>0</sup> + 2 * 3<sup>1</sup> + ... 2 * 3<sup>k - 1</sup> = 3<sup>k</sup> - 1. This might be enough for you to intuit the answer: that the total number of inner-loop iterations is bounded by a constant multiple of the number of inner-loop iterations on the last iteration of the outer loop, which in turn is bounded by *n*.

But if you want to *prove* it, then you can observe that the sum in the previous bound expression is itself bounded by a related definite integral:

= O(∫<sub>0</sub><sup>log *n*</sup> 3<sup>*i*</sup> d*i*)

... and *that* has a closed-form solution:

= O((3<sup>log *n*</sup> - 3<sup>0</sup>) / log 3)

, which clearly has a simpler bound itself

= O(3<sup>log *n*</sup>)

.  Exponentials of logarithms reduce to linear functions of the logarithm argument. Since we need only an asymptotic bound, we don't care about the details, and thus we can go straight to

= O(n)